# Tikz: Remove blank space around standalone document containing tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, graphics

I see many similar posts, but trying all of the suggestions has not solved my problem. I have a tikz picture as the only content in a standalone document. The goal is to produce an image for a printed board based on the template [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.thegamecrafter.com/templates/big-mat.png).

The code I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\cutlinet{38.0/300.0}
\def\cutlinel{42.0/300.0}
\def\cutlineb{3034.0/300.0}
\def\cutliner{4838.0/300.0}

\def\foldlinex{2440.0/300.0}

\def\height{3075.0/300.0}
\def\width{4875.0/300.0}

\newcommand{\drawoverlay}{%
    \node [anchor=south west, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[angle=90, width=16.25in, height=10.25in] {big-mat.png}};
}

\newcommand{\drawguides}{%
    \draw [blue] (\cutlinel,0) -- (\cutlinel,\height);
    \draw [blue] (\cutliner,0) -- (\cutliner,\height);
    \draw [blue] (0,\cutlinet) -- (\width,\cutlinet);
    \draw [blue] (0,\cutlineb) -- (\width,\cutlineb);

    \draw [blue] (\foldlinex,0) -- (\foldlinex,\height);
}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]

\drawoverlay
\drawguides

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can see many explicit attempts to remove margins and borders from the image. I have no idea which are necessary (I think outer sep and the noindent shouldn't be, but I don't know).

Even with all of these attempts the resulting document is not quite the right size:

```
$ pdfinfo output.pdf
Creator:         XeTeX output 2018.08.26:2025
Producer:       xdvipdfmx (20180217)
CreationDate:   Sun Aug 26 20:25:04 2018 EDT
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      1170.4 x 738.4 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      488406 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Note that the page size is about 16.26x10.256in, while the result *should* be 16.25x10.25in.

Opening up the document I can clearly see some space above and to the right of it. Is there any way to remove that space?

Comment: The edit is incorrect. I want to remove the whitespace that tikz creates. The title *was* to be parsed as "Tikz: Remove whitespace ..." perhaps better would be "Tikz adds whitespace ..." or "Remove added whitespace ... by Tikz"

Comment: The white space is part of the `PNG` you're using. Ti*k*Z isn't adding it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the PNG you are using:

> [image: original PNG]

Here is the output from your code:

> [image: Ti*k*Zed PNG]

Ti*k*Z isn't adding white space. The white space is in the PNG.

Comment: That's a little embarrassing. I just assumed that unexpected whitespace had to be a tikz problem since I have that problem so often, but you are right - its hiding in the image!

Comment: @LambdaBeta It does do that, I agree. But, this time, it is not guilty. I guess there's a reason they don't tell juries whether defendants have a criminal record already :-).